# When does type information flow backwards in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction, ctad

I just watched Stephan T. Lavavej talk at `CppCon 2018` on "Class Template Argument Deduction", where at [some point](https://youtu.be/-H-ut6j1BYU?t=941) he incidentally says:

> In C++ type information almost never flows backwards ... **I had to say "almost" because there's one or two cases, possibly more but very few**.

Despite trying to figure out which cases he might be referring to, I couldn't come up with anything. Hence the question:

**In which cases the C++17 standard mandates that type information  propagate backwards?**

Comment: pattern matching partial specialization and destructuring assignments.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Here is at least one case:

```
struct foo {
  template<class T>
  operator T() const {
    std::cout << sizeof(T) << "\n";
    return {};
  }
};
```

if you do `foo f; int x = f;  double y = f;`, type information will flow "backwards" to figure out what `T` is in `operator T`.

You can use this in a more advanced way:

```
template<class T>
struct tag_t {using type=T;};

template<class F>
struct deduce_return_t {
  F f;
  template<class T>
  operator T()&&{ return std::forward<F>(f)(tag_t<T>{}); }
};
template<class F>
deduce_return_t(F&&)->deduce_return_t<F>;

template<class...Args>
auto construct_from( Args&&... args ) {
  return deduce_return_t{ [&](auto ret){
    using R=typename decltype(ret)::type;
    return R{ std::forward<Args>(args)... };
  }};
}
```

so now I can do

```
std::vector<int> v = construct_from( 1, 2, 3 );
```

and it works.

Of course, why not just do `{1,2,3}`?  Well, `{1,2,3}` isn't an expression.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
v.emplace_back( construct_from(1,2,3) );
```

which, admittedly, require a bit more wizardry: [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bef3c7738b184f3f).  (I have to make the deduce return do a SFINAE check of F, then make the F be SFINAE friendly, *and* I have to block std::initializer_list in deduce_return_t operator T.)

Comment: Very interesting answer, and I learned a new trick so thank you very much! I had to add a template deduction guideline to [make your example compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90cd3d45b76a77ae), but other than that it works like a charm!

Comment: The `&&` qualifier on the `operator T()` is a great touch; it helps avoid the poor interaction with `auto` by causing a compilation error if `auto` is misused here.

Comment: That's very impressive, could you point me to some reference/talk to the idea in the example? or maybe it's original :) ...

Comment: @tootsie No, it is an aggregate, and I used `{}`.  I may need a deduction guide but I'm uncertain.  Please note you could do this in 4 times the code and be twice as clear; I was being terse in my adding of a new language feature as a header file `#include` here.

Comment: @lili Which idea?  I count 5: Using operator T to deduce return types?  Using tags to pass the deduced type to a lambda?  Using conversion operators to roll-your-own placement object construction?  Connecting all 4?

Comment: @Yakk I meant the "more advanced way" example in your answer. If it's from some talk/reference/project, I'd like to read more.

Comment: I see what you mean..but my gcc only accepts it as an aggregate when I pass the type explicitly, something like.. `auto l = <lambda>; return deduce_return_t<decltype(l)>{move(l)};`

Comment: @toot c++17 and deduction guide should fix it too

Comment: @lili Tha "more advanced way" example is, as I said, just 4 or so ideas glued together.  I did the gluing on the fly for this post, but I certainly have seen many pairs or even triplets of those used together.  It is a bunch of reasonably obscure techniques (as tootsie complains), but nothing novel.

Comment: @Justin, could you please elaborate on how does the `&&` qualifier help produce an error in case `auto` is used? Actually, `auto` [does compile and run for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3pUhkARKKS02vhzR). Am I missing anything here?

Comment: @Mike It's not an easy situation to explain, but note that in your example, you are misusing this tool. In production code, the `f` member would be private. The `&&` qualifier means that someone can't accidentally write `auto result = construct_from(1, 2, 3)` and expect `result` to hold the value, whereas without the `&&` qualifier, if someone used `result`, it might just compile since the conversion could happen late. This can be a problem since the evaluation could happen multiple times if `result` is used multiple times, or it could actually cause bugs related to lifetime

Comment: @Justin, Nice explanation, thanks. A definitely clever use case for the `&&` qualifier.

Answer (score 32):

[Stephan T. Lavavej explained the case he was talking about in a tweet](https://twitter.com/StephanTLavavej/status/1062100817140842496):

> The case I was thinking of is where you can take the address of an overloaded/templated function and if it’s being used to initialize a variable of a specific type, that will disambiguate which one you want. (There’s a list of what disambiguates.)

we can see examples of this from [cppreference page on Address of overloaded function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address), I have excepted a few below:

```
int f(int) { return 1; } 
int f(double) { return 2; }   

void g( int(&f1)(int), int(*f2)(double) ) {}

int main(){
    g(f, f); // selects int f(int) for the 1st argument
             // and int f(double) for the second

     auto foo = []() -> int (*)(int) {
        return f; // selects int f(int)
    }; 

    auto p = static_cast<int(*)(int)>(f); // selects int f(int)
}
```

[Michael Park adds](https://twitter.com/mcypark/status/1062152906197979136):

> It's not limited to initializing a concrete type, either. It could also infer just from the number of arguments

and provides [this live example](https://godbolt.org/z/YyrO5V):

```
void overload(int, int) {}
void overload(int, int, int) {}

template <typename T1, typename T2,
          typename A1, typename A2>
void f(void (*)(T1, T2), A1&&, A2&&) {}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3,
          typename A1, typename A2, typename A3>
void f(void (*)(T1, T2, T3), A1&&, A2&&, A3&&) {}

int main () {
  f(&overload, 1, 2);
}
```

which I elaborate a little [more here](https://godbolt.org/z/XzmpvD).

Comment: We could also describe this as: cases where the type of an expression depends on the context?

Answer (score 20):

I believe in static casting of overloaded functions the flow goes the opposite direction as in usual overload resolution. So one of those is backwards, I guess.

Comment: I believe this is correct.  And it is when you pass a function name to a function pointer type; type information flows from the context of the expression (the type you are assigning to/constructing/etc) backwards into the name of the function to determine which overload is chosen.