# Is it possible to do a no-copy emplace into map while using aggregate initialization?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, stdmap, aggregate-initialization

See this answer for how to insert into [stdmap](/questions/tagged/stdmap) without making copies of the map value.

[std::map emplace without copying value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960325/stdmap-emplace-without-copying-value)

Continueing from that answer - suppose my `Foo` type looks something like this:

```
struct Foo {
  const int& intref_; 
  std::mutex mutex_;
}
```

Then initialized using aggregate-initialization like this

```
Foo{7}
```

or

```
Foo{7, std::mutex()}
```

Would it be somehow possible to be emplaced into the map with type ?:

```
std::map<size_t, Foo> mymap;
```

I know I could just write a constructor for `Foo` - but can it be done with aggregate initialization instead ?

**Link to compiler explorer:**

https://godbolt.org/z/_Fm4k1

**Relevant c++ references:**

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened when you did?

Comment: @davidbak I did try it directly and it doesn't work on any major compiler

Comment: then perhaps a link to a coliru example with the example and compiler error message copied here would make your question better ... just a suggestion

Comment: @davidbak I can provide you the small code for the testing - but I do not think it is worth it to provide the compile error I see with a 'naive' approach.

Comment: mutex does not have a copy constructor. Why is the mutex there? Don't you want a new mutex for each object? Do you want all objects to share the same mutex? Or each object have it's own?

Comment: maybe.  compiler errors are usually helpful.  did you try the `std::piecewise_construct` overload mentioned in an answer at the linked question:  That might get around the problem that mutex is not copyable or movable.

Comment: @davidbak I have provided some copy paste test code

Comment: @KamilCuk no - in my case it is fine the struct cannot be copied as a result of having the mutex member - it also has a reference which cannot be default copied either

Comment: thus, piecewise construct?

Comment: @davidbak In my example i use the try-emplace and it gives the same behavior as the piecewise construct - just in case I did try it and it didn't change anything.

Comment: You don't upvote the question. What can I do to improve it ?

Comment: are you asking me? i thought i suggested a) providing a link to an online compiler example, and b) providing the error message.  it's just my personal preference that C++ questions include that sort of thing as a matter of course.  But don't get upset: anyone can vote or not vote for any reason.  Right now I'm puzzled why the line `M m{7};` compiles and I'm trying to figure that out.

Comment: In fact, I tried the example on wandbox with clang 7 and it warns on the line `M m{7}`: missing field 'm_' initializer [-Wmissing-field-initializers].  So maybe that's broken too.

Comment: @davidbak It compiles, because there is a rule that the remaining members gets default initialized.

Comment: ok, idnkt. ....

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is that forwarding arguments (e.g., what emplace and try_emplace do)  isn't the same as aggregate initialization, and that's that.  You've got to have a matching constructor.  Hopefully later today some C++ expert will chime in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may [exploit casts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53270355/4832499) to indirect your construction

```
template<typename T>
struct tag { using type = T; };

template<typename F>
struct initializer
{
    F f;
    template<typename T>
    operator T() &&
    {
        return std::forward<F>(f)(tag<T>{});
    }
};

template<typename F>
initializer(F&&) -> initializer<F>;

template<typename... Args>
auto initpack(Args&&... args)
{
    return initializer{[&](auto t) {
        using Ret = typename decltype(t)::type;
        return Ret{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    }};
}
```

And use it as

```
struct Foo
{
  const int& intref_; 
  std::mutex mutex_;
};

void foo()
{
    int i = 42;
    std::map<int, Foo> m;
    m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
              std::forward_as_tuple(0),
              std::forward_as_tuple(initpack(i)));
}
```

Note you can't prolong a temporary's lifetime by binding it to a non-stack reference.

Comment: I can't seem to find a workaround to achieve this in C++11, Is it possible? or I'm obligated to define a constructor?

Comment: @Ikeike It's impossible without guaranteed copy elision.

Answer (score 4):

It's not insomuch a problem with `std::map::try_emplace`, as it is with `std::pair`. As this simple declaration will reproduce an error rooted in the same problem:

```
std::pair<const int, Foo> p(
    std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(0),
    std::forward_as_tuple(i)
);
```

And it's not really a problem with `std::pair` alone. As the abstract of [n4462](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4462.html) details, it's pretty prevalent. Simply put, that pair c'tor (as do many library functions) does its forwarding like this:

```
second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
```

So no curly braces, and as such no aggregate initialization in C++17, only value initialization. Your only options are to define an actual c'tor, or use something like **Passer By**'s [clever solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54982264/817643).

If you can use C++20, then ([p0960](https://wg21.link/p0960)) was accepted, which allows initializing an aggregate from a parenthesized list of values. This addresses n4462, and allows user code to perfect forward initializers for aggregate too.

Comment: Any update in 2023 with C++20 ?

Comment: @WaterFox - Yes, the paper is now a reality, not a possibility :)